# Flood table not respecting X_FORWARDED_FOR

Tags: cdn, proxies

The flood table IPs are listing the IP of the load balancer, not the one of the request, which is in the X_FORWARDED_FOR header.

I have the 'reverse_proxy' set to `TRUE` in setting.php, and it works with the CDN as expected, but not with the flood table.

The site hosted at AWS using the CloudFront CDN.

How can I make the flood table look at the IP reported in the X_FORWARDED_FOR header?

Comment: [`ip_address()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/ip_address/7) should check for `X_FORWARDED_FOR` if `reverse_proxy` is set to true, might be worth stepping through that function with an appropriate request to see what's happening

Comment: it's odd.  I setup an new load balancer pointing to a new ec2 instance, and the X_FORWARDED_FOR is being properly set and respected in the flood table.  I'd rather not have to setup debugging in prod if it's at all avoidable.

Comment: I did a quick test in prod, and the X_FORWARDED_FOR headers are set.  However, I just had to clear the flood table of ips from my load balancer.

Comment: Now my followup question to this is how to handle a revolving ip...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses']` had my old load balancer IP, thanks to AWS changing the IP without telling me.  Once I updated with the current LB address, it worked as expected.